# Generic polynomial and irreduciblity.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $p= x^2+ ax+b \in R[x] $ where $R= \mathbb{F}[a,b], a$ and $b$ are indeterminates over $F$.

It is mentioned that $p$ is a generic polynomial and it is irreducible, Since specialising the variables(a=0 and b=t) gives $\tilde p= x^2-t $ which is irreducible over $F[t][x]$.

My questions are

1. What is the meaning of generic polynomial?
   In general, what is the meaning of the generic element?.
2. how does the actual process of specialising variables work?
3. why $\tilde p $ is irreducible?

Kindly help me with this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

-*I can't comment due to less points!*

- a generic polynomial refers usually to a polynomial whose coefficients are indeterminates.
- You can use Gauss Lemma, Eisenstein's Criteria and **Reduction Mod n** method to find if, a given polynomial is irreducible or not.
- we'll try with Reduction Mod n with example.. ${P= x^2-15x+7}$, we can take mod7 but it can't tell any thing about irreducibility over Z. so we we'll try mod 5.
- P(x) mod5 = ${x^2+2}$ = ${x^2+b}$,  now making a=0 it is a good choice to test irreducibility.
- Now if it factor then we're left with (x+t1)(x+t2), so we need ${t1 \cdot t2 =2 =b}$, now,the perfect square in the ${Z_5} $ are {0,1,4}, but 2 doesn't appear.
- Also [a,b] are field elements, hence it doesn't have zero devisors.
- Hence if it is irrecucible over ${Z_n}$ then it is irreducible over ${Z}$
- And Due to Gauss Lemma, if it is irreducible over Z, it is irreducible over Q.